# How do you make a trail of mobs in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was watching the video below, and was wondering how do you make a trail of armor stands?

Would it be possible to make a trail of zombies or a trail of sheep?

Comment: could you specify where in this 7 minute video is the information your talking about?

Comment: @Ender it's around 5:50

Answer (score 0):

Now, I didn't test this, but you could make it so each zombie, every few ticks, summons a witherSkull entity that gets added a point on a scoreboard objective every tick, and when the skull has a few points, the next zombie in line is teleported to it, then after the points is twice the amount when the first zomb. is tele'd, then the next one gets teleported, and then the skull entity is killed. Hope this works! ~(null) I used this answer in another Q, so it's not exactly relavant. Here was that post: [How do you make mobs follow each other in a trail?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221925/how-do-you-make-mobs-follow-each-other-in-a-trail/221930#221930)