# How do you make mobs follow each other in a trail?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to make a new mob for part of a big project but the problem is that I can't figure out how to make mobs follow eachother... I was going to make it so that I have 3 zombies... Ones the lead and another is following behind... The third zombie will be following that one... Is this even possible? Help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could use a similar method to what SethBling used in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ixJodHSeDY) – get each zombie to start tracking a villager (by allowing each zombie to hit its own villager once), then teleport each zombie's villager to (slightly above or below) where you want it to pathfind to (e.g. above the next zombie in the line).

Answer (score 0):

Now, I didn't test this, but you could make it so each zombie, every few ticks, summons a witherSkull entity that gets added a point on a scoreboard objective every tick, and when the skull has a few points, the next zombie in line is teleported to it, then after the points is twice the amount when the first zombie is teleported, then the next one gets teleported, and then the skull entity is killed. Hope this works!

Comment: Hey there.  I think you might want to clear up your description a little bit.  I kind of understand what you're trying to say, but I think cleaning up the grammar would make it more straight forward.

Comment: Could use help with that

Comment: I don't know how that works user114351